# django form gettting error while posting data

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Hi Eeveryone I am Trying to creating data using django form but getting error and i tried multiple method but sometime stored data but not based on city, i need to restore data based on city, kindly help me out.

***model.py***

```
class Incentive(BaseModel):
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False,
    null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, 
    null=True, blank=True)
    no_of_trips=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True, blank=True)
    incentive=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(
        City,
        models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='City',
        null=True, blank=True
    )
```

***form.py***

```
class IncentiveForm(forms.ModelForm):
    city_id = CityModelChoiceField(
        required=False, queryset=City.objects.all(), label='City', widget=Select2Widget)
    
    class Meta:
        model=Incentive
        fields= ['start_date','end_date','no_of_trips','incentive']
        
    
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):              
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(IncentiveForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

***views.py***

```
def incentive_form(request,city_id=None):
    city = City.objects.get(pk=city_id)
    create=Incentive.objects.filter(city_id=city_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=IncentiveForm(request.POST,city_id=city_id)
        if form.is_valid():
            start_date=form.cleaned_data['start_date']
            end_date=form.cleaned_data['end_date']
            no_of_trips=form.cleaned_data['no_of_trips']
            incentive=form.cleaned_data['incentive']
            if create is not None:
                create.start_date=start_date
                create.end_date=end_date
                create.no_of_trips=no_of_trips
                create.incentive=incentive
                create.city_id=city_id           
                create.save()
                messages.success(request,'Incentive data created successfully!')
            
    else:
        form=IncentiveForm()

        
    context={
        'menu_incentive': 'active',
        'submenu_incentive_list': 'active',
        'city_id': city_id,
        'city': city,
        'form':form,


    }
    return render(request,"hiringprocess/incentive.html",context=context)
```

***urls.py*** path('incentive/int:city_id/add',views.incentive_form,name="incentive_form")

***city*** this is city model

```
class City(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=80)
    employee_series = models.CharField('Name', max_length=3)
    available_employee_id = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

***traceback***

```
return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Ashish Pandey\everest_jarvis\fleet\views.py", line 3408, in incentive_form
    form=IncentiveForm(request.POST,city_id=city_id)
  File "E:\Ashish Pandey\everest_jarvis\fleet\forms.py", line 709, in __init__
    super(IncentiveForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'city_id'
ERROR "POST /fleet/incentive/1/add HTTP/1.1" 500 86701
```

Comment: update your question with `traceback`

Comment: @sunilghimire updated

Comment: try `create=Incentive.objects.filter(city_id=city)` and this is not working update your `Incentive` model

Comment: still same error

Comment: add city_id to fields in form.

Comment: update your code of your model `Incentive`

Comment: added incentive model

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get a `Incentive` instance if exist in order to update it's values.
In your code, `Incentive.objects.filter(city_id=city_id)` returns a queryset, not a object instance. To get a instance (or null if not exists) you can:

```py
try:
    incentive = Incentive.objects.filter(city_id=city_id)[0]
except IndexError:
    incentive = None
```

or more easy:  `incentive = Incentive.objects.filter(city_id=city_id).first()`.
Now, `incentive` is an `Incentive` instance or `None` if it not exists.

Second, a `ModelForm` automaticaly sets the properties to a model with the `save` method. You don't need set it manually with `start_date=form.cleaned_data['start_date']`. You only need set the correct model instance in the forms constructor, with the `instance` parameter. If the `instance` is `None`, the form creates itself a new one to save in the DB.

Bringing it all together:

```py
def incentive_form(request,city_id=None):
    # Best replace this line with city = get_object_or_404(City, pk=city_id)
    city = City.objects.get(pk=city_id)
    incentive = Incentive.objects.filter(city_id=city_id).first()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = IncentiveForm(instance=incentive, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save() # <- This returns the upadted or created instance.
            messages.success(request,'Incentive data created successfully!')
            # After the messages, best sends a redirect to prevent the user 
            # re-sends the form  when try to refresh the page. 
            # The next example returns to the same url.
            return HttResponseRedirect(request.path)
    else:
        # This loads the instance values in the form
        form = IncentiveForm(instance=incentive)

    # ....
```

Comment: thankyou sir using this method record created but not based on city, i want to store data based on city, pls help me

Comment: `city` field is in your models? Add it to `fields= ['start_date','end_date','no_of_trips','incentive']` in the form as  @mehedi  says.

Comment: city is a foreign key, before i used city_id field in form now using city field but still not store data based on city